# Spring Boot CrudRepository search @ElementCollection map keys

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with:

```
@Id
Long id

String username;

@ElementCollection
private Map<String, Boolean> emails;
```

I have the repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, UserDao {
    User findOneByUsername(String username);

    // This does not work, how do I make it?
    @Query("select u from User u WHERE ? in u.emails.keySet")
    User findOneByQueryForEmail
}
```

What method signature (and @Query annotation) can I use to implement the `findOneByQueryForEmail` that will search the `keySet` of the emails `Map` for a value?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below approach

```
@Query("select u from User u WHERE KEY(u.emails) in :emails")

 User findOneByQueryForEmail(@Param("emails") List<String> emails)
```